# Is this javascript, and where should I place it

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I came accross this html multiple file upload tutorial: http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/

I'm new to web programming enough to not being able to understand how to make a code from the two sections of the 'complete code' in this tutorial, which basically are:

A. Some html code:

```
<h3>Choose file(s)</h3>
<p>
    <input id="files-upload" type="file" multiple>
</p>
<p id="drop-area">
    <span class="drop-instructions">or drag and drop files here</span>
    <span class="drop-over">Drop files here!</span>
</p>

<ul id="file-list">
    <li class="no-items">(no files uploaded yet)</li>
</ul>
```

B. And some javascript:

```
(function () {
    var filesUpload = document.getElementById("files-upload"),
        dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area"),
        fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");

    function uploadFile (file) {
[etc]
```

I recognize the code, but I don't understand where a part of code beginning with (function () is supposed to go into my code.

So my question is: how should the javascript part be placed in my code.

[Edit]

Thanks for your complementary answers!

Comment: are you using HTML5 ? if not you cant use the above.. try this jquery http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Problem with the blueimp one is that I need to follow this flow for each file:
1. Upload (Post) the file to an aspx page, then posting to the same page with another parameter, and fetching the result and displaying this result into a button or any of the listed input. (The list being the list of files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either just before the `</body>` tag, between a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag like this:

```
<body>

    <!-- other stuff -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        // this is your function's core
    })();
    </script>

</body>
```

Or within the `<head></head>` tag, also between a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`, but you have (probably) to wait until the DOM correctly loaded. For example, using jQuery:

```
<head>

    <!-- other stuff -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        (function () {
            // this is your function's core
        })();
    });
    </script>

</head>
```

Or even within an external JavaScript file, where you'll also have (probably) to wait until the DOM correctly loaded. For example, once again using jQuery:

file *myScripts.js*

```
$(function() {
    (function () {
        // this is your function's core
    })();
});
```

file *myDocument.html*

```
<head>

    <!-- other stuff -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/myScripts.js"></script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the javascript inside `<script></script>` tags after your upload form.

The post you linked to has a complete working demo of the code it describes which can be found here:
http://robertnyman.com/html5/fileapi-upload/fileapi-upload.html

A good way to experiment with this kind of code snippet is to paste the required section into a tool like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is placed inside `onClick`, `onMouseOver`, etc. attributes, as well as inside `<script type="text/javascript">` tags.

They can be anywhere inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags (place it after the elements you are accessing, so that they load).

[w3 Schools](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp) has a Javascript reference to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a file with .js extension so yourFile.js.
- Put your java-script code in it...
- At the end of HTML file place this inside:

`<script src="yourFile.js"></script>`

- Make sure your js is in the same directory as is your html...

Answer (score 0):

Since the code includes `getElementById` but nothing like `window.onload` or any other deferring tactic, it MUST be placed AFTER the form you want it to affect. To be on the safe side, you can place it in a `<script>` tag immediately before `</body>`.